# Apache: Add a prefix to all URLs in a virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

In one of my machines I have an internal server which listens at port `8090`. I am using a `virtualhost` in Apache to proxy the internal server using a URL like `servera.mydomain.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAlias servera.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass         /     http://localhost:8090/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse  /     http://localhost:8090/
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This works well, and when I open `https://servera.mydomain.com` from my browser it redirects me to `http://localhost:8090/`.

The problem is that all the urls in the server begin with ReportServer, and therefor I actually have to type `https://servera.mydomain.com/ReportServer` in order to access it, which is cumbersome.

I have tried:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ReportServer/$1
```

But I only get 404 errors without good explanation in the logs.

**What's the proper way to put a `ReportServer` prefix in all URLs in the virtualhost? Can I choose whether the prefix will be visible to the browser or not?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ProxyPass         /     http://localhost:8090/ReportServer nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /     http://localhost:8090/ReportServer
```